# PHP - Stopping the execution of the calling function

Tags: php, call, execution

This is a little difficult to explain, but i'll try my best.

This is similar to the code i'm currently running.

```
function func1()
{

     func2()

}

function func2()
{

     exit();

}
```

I need to be able to stop the execution of func1 from within func2, but I need a better way to do it than exit(). Since the caller of func1 might have other operations to do, I don't want to stop them as well, I just want to stop the rest of func1 from executing.

I'm aware that I could put a simple if statement in func1 to detect the return value of func2 and then return if it's a certain value, but that's a bit messy too.

So my question is, how can I stop the execution of the remainder of the caller function, from within a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a value and check for it.

```
function func1()
{
    $result = func2();
    if ($result === 0) return;

    // Your func1 code here
}

function func2()
{
    if ( ... ) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: And no, this isn't considered messy... that's how functions are supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Checking a return value isn't messy. It's standard practice.  You basically have two options:

- Check return values.
- Throw an exception in func2.  If it's uncaught in func1 it'll bubble up higher and stop execution in both functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way this will work.

Remember: `func2()` could be called from ANYWHERE, not only `func1()`. How would you know that it is func1 you are stopping.

Whatever it is that made you think interrupting the calling function would solve the problem - think again, and tell us about the bigger picture for proper advice.