# how to execute remaining code after calling another method within same controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, frameworks

I'm using laravel 5.8. There are two functions in my laravel controller. After calling one function into another remaining code does not execute. Is there a way to execute the remaining body of function? I have tried calling function without return statement function is not called.

```php
public function a(){
    return "function a";
}

public function b(){
    return $this->a();
 // after the above statement remaining code does not execute
    echo "function b";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` keyword gives the answer to your confusion. Return means execute this line and exit the function. Of course it will not continue with the rest of the code. 
It depends what you want to do with the result of the first function, but if you want the result you can store it in a variable and use it for other calculation, for example this will work:

```
public function b(){
    $result = $this->a();

    echo "function b and result of a: " . $result;
}
```

--- EDIT

After your comment below, the best way to check if user is logged in or not is not to have a separate function for that but you can achieve that using a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware). So instead of having separate function, on your route you can define it as this:

```
Route::get('endpoint', 'YourController@b')->middleware('auth');
```

This middleware will redirect the user to the login page unless he is logged in.

If none of the above is considered as solution for your case, then I found a duplicate question as your original one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368937/php-stopping-the-execution-of-the-calling-function).

Comment: this makes sense. But what if i don't want to use the output of "function a()". I just want to call it and then rest of the code should automatically be executed. I tried it by simply calling it "$this->a();" but using this "function a" didn't executed.

Comment: it does execute but not using the result of it it means it executes in void.. Try in your function a instead of `return`,  `echo` the result and call it, you will see the output.

Comment: Why do you think the function isn't executed?

Comment: @nakov yes it executed Thanks. But is there a way without using `echo` or `return` the function does not run in void. and entire function body should run normally.?

Comment: it always runs my friend but in order to see a result you've got to use one of the options I have already given. I really don't understand your use case in order to give more details. But either you print a result or not by just calling the function its body is being executed for sure.

Comment: @nakov Actually i created function to check whether user is logged in. If user is not logged in then redirect user to login page. After using 'return' or 'echo'. Function is executing properly. but not without it.

Comment: Look at my edit, it answers your last comment in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite normal reaction for PHP

Please check manual of "return" from here:
https://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

It says "... If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.  ..."

I hope this helps.

Comment: this makes sense. But what if i don't want to use the output of "function a()". I just want to call it and then rest of the code should automatically be executed. I tried it by simply calling it "$this->a();" but using this "function a" didn't executed.

Comment: yes this is normal. Without using return or saving its output in a variable, "function a" does not execute. I simply tried this "$this->a();" but in this way "function a" didn't executed.

Comment: have you tried changing "return "function a";" line with "echo "function a";" ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the data returned from function `a` in function `b` ?

```
public function a()
{
    $collection = DB::table('foo')->get();

    return $collection;
}


public function b()
{
    $data = $this->a();

    // Do something 
    dd( $data );

}
```